# Read schedule expression of Kubernetes CronJob from ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kubernetes-cronjob

I've more that 10 CronJobs configured in Kubernetes and all working properly as expected.

Now I am planning add 20 more CronJobs. All jobs getting data from external resources, processing it and generating some kind of reports.

I want to configure schedule expression of CronJobs into ConfigMap. for example something like,

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: scheduler-config
  namespace: test
data:
  job1.schedule.expression: */1 * * * *
  job2.schedule.expression: */5 * * * *
  job3.schedule.expression: */30 * * * *
  job4.schedule.expression: 0 1 * * *
  job5.schedule.expression: 0 0 * * THU
```

I want to make it more flexible if possible, for example if I update the ConfigMap with new expression then CronJob should be updated with new schedule expression and next time it should run as per new expression value in ConfigMap.

Comment: As far as I know ConfigMap is used to set environment variables inside container or is mounted as volume. I don't think you can use configmap to set schedule in cronjob. Maybe you could use [helm cronjobs](https://github.com/bambash/helm-cronjobs) as an alernative for that?

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're asking. What does using the configmap get you? Why not just update `spec.schedule` in the corresponding cronjob?

Comment: I've many cronjobs, updating spec.schedule of each cronjob is very time consuming, It's better if I can put all the scheduler in one config and apply it whenever required.

Comment: You could write a small program that listens to the changes to the configmap, and when it gets a notification, it reconfigures all the cronjobs programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in comments

As far as I know [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) is used to set environment variables inside container or is mounted as volume. I don't think you can use configmap to set schedule in cronjob.

---

As an alternative you could use [helm cronjobs](https://github.com/bambash/helm-cronjobs) for that and specify the schedules in [values.yaml](https://github.com/bambash/helm-cronjobs/blob/master/values.yaml).

Take a look at below cronjobs created with above helm cronjobs.

```
kubectl get cronjob
NAME                     SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE    LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
cold-fly-hello-env-var   * * * * *     False     0         23s             1m
cold-fly-hello-ubuntu    */5 * * * *   False     0         23s             1m
cold-fly-hello-world     * * * * *     False     0         23s             1m
```

And their schedule vlaues [there](https://github.com/bambash/helm-cronjobs/blob/master/values.yaml#L10), [there](https://github.com/bambash/helm-cronjobs/blob/master/values.yaml#L51) and [there](https://github.com/bambash/helm-cronjobs/blob/master/values.yaml#L21).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and see if it fits in my use-case or not